# a question from the GMAT test

Tags: meaning

*From the GMAT test:*

*Gall's hypothesis **of there being different mental functions localized in different parts of the brain is widely accepted today.***

*A. of there being different mental functions localized in different parts of the brain is widely accepted today.*

*B. of different mental functions that are localized in different parts of the brain is widely accepted today.*

*C. that different mental functions are localized in different parts of the brain is widely accepted today.*

*D. which is that there are different mental functions localized in different parts of the brain is widely accepted today.*

*E. which is widely accepted today is that there are different mental functions localized in different parts of the brain.*

I would like to know why the choice B does not fit. The right answer is C. In terms of the choice B the explanation is as follows: B is "grammatically correct but Incorrect" because "per this choice we do not know precisely what the hypothesis is". I do not understand this. I get the information about the the content of the hypothesis (hypothesis of different mental functions). I am not able to see any difference between B and C alternatives.

Comment: The entire *concept* of ruling any of the phrasings "correct" or "incorrect" seems to me a case of pedantry taken to ridiculous extremes. But I suppose the test-setter thinks B is somehow flawed because although it references the "different functions", it doesn't do this with a form of TO BE to explicitly state that they ***exist***. But contextually they obviously *must* exist, if only in order to be the grammatical subject of ***are** localized*. Basically, I think the test-setter is an idiot.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I don't agree.  If you parse the 'B' sentence carefully, you will notice that the description of the hypothesis (starting with "different" and ending with "brain") lacks a predicate altogether.  The part of it that begins with "that are" is not the predicate but an adjective clause describing "functions".

Comment: @Victor Bazarov: You should apply for a job setting GMAT exam questions! If *you* parse B carefully, you should be able to see that *of [**the existence of**] different mental functions* is contextually,  syntactically, and epistemologically implicit. And knowledge of how English is actually used should confirm that this is a perfectly normal feature of the language. I maintain that this isn't a matter of grammar, but of misguided pedantic semantics.

Comment: You don't have to insult me to drive your point home, you know...

Comment: To everyone, it's worth noting that in GMAT sentence correction questions, the test requires the test taker to "[choose the answer that produces the most effective sentence; this answer should be clear and exact, without awkwardness, ambiguity, redundancy, or grammatical error.](https://books.google.com/books?id=6rpvAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT1074&lpg=PT1074)" It's easy for a learner to fall into a common misconception that the answer is the only (grammatically?) correct choice, while in fact, the test wants "the most effect sentence". My maxim for this is "GMAT is about the best, not the correct answer."

Comment: @DamkerngT. - That seems to mean that grammatically incorrect (or badly worded) sentence can still be the answer because somebody thinks that it's "the best".  Are sentence's being proper and well worded still criteria for selecting it?

Comment: @VictorBazarov Not really. "Best" is my own word. It's easy for me to remember what GMAT wants by just remembering that it's about "best", not only "correct". The description the official guide uses is, imho, clear enough. The answer should fulfill all criteria: it has to be (the most) effective, clear, exact; without awkwardness, ambiguity, redundancy, or grammatical error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with B:

**My hypothesis, of ice-cream with celebrity visages on the carton, being sold in supermarkets nowadays, is widely accepted.**

OK, what is that hyphothesis? Does the consumer think the ice cream is more delicious?  Is the consumer more likely to develop brand loyalty if the ice-cream is associated with a celebrity they like?

Now, with a predicate:

**My hypothesis, that celebrity visages on ice-cream cartons develop strong brand loyalty in the consumer, is widely accepted.**

Answer (score 0):

While it is admittedly arbitrary, this is simply an issue of memorizing: part of GMAT Sentence Correction is learning preferred idiomatic phrasings. These are commonly called "idioms" in GMAT-speak, but I find that term annoying.

Examples of these would be:
"different from,"
"laws requiring" (that is, "laws" takes the gerund),
"indicate that,"
or "dated at" (this is a special circumstance discussing archaeological dating).

In short, the GMAT prefers "hypothesis that" over "hypothesis of." Learn that and you'll fine.

Comment: That does not seem to answer why it was seen as correct but not preferred. Can you clarify what you think is going on here?

Comment: While the Official Guide answers (A or C or whichever) will be correct, the explanations themselves are quite frankly questionable at best and definitively NOT written by the writer of the question. I would simply ignore this and move on to what the test actually wants. This is a good explanation of the "idiom" practice re: GMAT itself: https://blog.targettestprep.com/gmat-idioms/#What-is-a-GMAT-Idiom